# How to generate webpack.conf.js files when ejecting facebook / create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I ran:

```
npm run eject
```

on a create-react-app and it didn't generate webpack conf files. I was expecting two files something like this:

```
webpack.config.dev.js
webpack.config.prod.js
```

how do we generate those files or do we have to manually generate?

Comment: Guessing you can add a `config-overrides.js` to write `module.exports = {}` for customized settings for `react-app-rewired` created by `react-create-app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files ARE generated, they get placed in the config folder and are under the name ' webpack.config.js'. If they are not being generated, make sure to update your create-react-app command.